# Check if English language is set

Tags: objective-c, nslocale

I'd like to check which language is set on the device.

Here I get the language:

```
    NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

But how can I check if english is set with an if-statement?

Comment: "British English" is "en-GB", "American English" is "en-US". I believe. Either way it will **begin** with "en".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the description on [Apple's language designations page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpinternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html), which links to more complete lists for the language and region codes.  Looks like you're pretty safe just checking that the first two letters are "en".

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect: `if ([language isEqualToString:@"en"])`